# Transient Getter is persisted JPA Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transient

although I marked some getter methods in my class as `@Transient` (javax.persistence) the results when calling the method are persisted in the database:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Song")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Song implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "artist_id")
    private Artist artist;

      @Transient
    public static final Path MUSIC_DIRECTORY = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "TUBEMIRROR-MUSIC");

    @Transient
    public String getPathBySongId(){
        return Paths.get(MUSIC_DIRECTORY.toString(), this.getYoutubeId() + ".mp3").toString();
    }
}
```

Since there is a 1:1 relationship of songId to the path of the song on the filesystem I rather do not want to persist it. 
When I read the list of all songs in the database using a JPARepository I see that the field was persisted despite the notation.

Can someone tell me why this happens?

Comment: post the rest of your class

Comment: Please check that your persistent Entity classes have either field OR property-based annotations.

Comment: @DN1 I added everything from the class except the getters

Comment: @fisc I am fairly new to hibernate but I think that I have field based annotations?

Comment: The default is not FIELD. The access type is FIELD if you place mapping annotations on fields, and it's PROPERTY if you place mapping annotations on getters. And all the entity hierarchy must be coherent in the mapping annotation placement: always on fields, or always on getters, but not mixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using (JPA) annotations, you are supposed to annotate EITHER fields OR getters, but NOT BOTH. Your annotation of fields is being used and consequently the annotation of the transient **getter** (`getPathBySongId`) if being ignored. Annotate getters ONLY if you want that to be respected.

JPA annotations on a `static final` are pointless, since such fields are not persisted anyway

Answer (score 0):

Add @Access annotation on your class so jpa will consider only fields 
annotations

```
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
```

in your example :

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Table(name = "Song")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Song implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "artist_id")
    private Artist artist;

    public static final Path MUSIC_DIRECTORY = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "TUBEMIRROR-MUSIC");

    public String getPathBySongId(){
        return Paths.get(MUSIC_DIRECTORY.toString(), this.getYoutubeId() + ".mp3").toString();
    }
}
```

at least you will be able to see in logs why jpa would persist this one.